# Angular chain directives/ generate html from constant

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to chain to directives together in angular.  What I am trying to do is generate the following html in a directive.

```
<div id="menu-brunch" class="tab-pane">
    <div ng-init="init('brunch');" ng-controller="controllers.MenuController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{item.description}}</p>
            <menuitems model="item.items" ></menuitems>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Menu items is working, but no matter what I try I can't create a "double" directive.  The goal is to create another directive `menu` that will output the HTML above, e.g.:

```
<menu model='brunch'>
```

What I tried:

```
angular.module('leanwxApp.directives', []).
directive('menu', ()->
      template : "
            <div id='tab-{{model}}' class='tab-pane'>
<div ng-init=\"init('{{model}}');\" ng-controller='MenuController'>
                        <div ng-repeat='item in menuItems'>
                            <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
                            <p>{{item.description}}</p>
                            <menuitems model='item.items' ></menuitems>
                        </div>
            </div>
      ",
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope : {
        'model' : '=model'
      },
  ).directive('menuitems', ()->
      template : "
                  <ul class='media-list'>
                    <li ng-repeat=\"item in model\">
                        <div class='pull-right'>{{item.price}}</div>
                        <div class=\"media-body\">
                          <h4 class=\"media-heading\">{{item.name}}</h4>
                          <p ng-bind-html-unsafe=\"item.description\"></p>
                         </div> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
      ",
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope : {
        'model' : '=model'
      },
  );
```

But it just produces nothing... suggestions ?  And as a side note, my "MenuController" performs a JSON request with whatever `init('<category>')` is set with.  e.g. `/menu/<category>.json` .    Fiddle showing the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/ALWQe/

Comment: Can you put together a plunker or jsfiddle that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I think this shows it:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/ALWQe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/ALWQe/5/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="MenuController">
    <menu which="Brunch"></menu>
    <menu which="Lunch"></menu>
    <menu which="Dinner"></menu>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.factory('TestXXX', function () {
    return {
        test: function() { alert('load data here'); }
    };
});

app.directive('menu', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="menu-{{which}}" class="tab-pane">' +
        '    <div>' +
            '        <div ng-repeat="item in menu.items">' +
            '            <h3>{{menu.name}}</h3>' +
            '            <p>{{menu.description}}</p>' +
            '            <menuitems model="menu.items" ></menuitems>' +
            '         </div>' +
            '     </div>' +
            '</div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            which: '@'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, TestXXX) {
            TestXXX.test();
            $scope.$watch('which', function (which) {
                $scope.menu = {
                    'name': which + ' Menu',
                        'description': which + ' Description',
                    items: [{
                        'name': which + ' Item',
                            'description': which + ' Item Description',
                            'price': '1.99'
                    }]
                };
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('menuitems', function () {
    return {
        template: "<ul class='media-list'><li ng-repeat=\"item in model\">                      <div class='pull-right'>{{item.price}}</div><div class=\"media-body\">                        <h4 class=\"media-heading\">{{item.name}}</h4><p ng-bind-html-unsafe=\"item.description\"></p></div></li></ul>",
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            'model': '=model'
        }
    };
});

app.controller('MenuController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.loadMenu = function (which) {

    };


    $scope.menuItems = {
        'name': 'test',
            'description': 'description',
        items: [{
            'name': 'test 1',
                'description': 'item description',
                'price': '1.99'
        }, {
            'name': 'test 2',
                'description': 'item description',
                'price': '2.99'
        }]
    };
});
```

The Fiddle you provided had some issues.  It might be better to describe your goal instead of describing what you're trying to do with the AngularJS framework.  I don't think it's a good idea for a directive to load data from the server (my assumption based on reading your question over), but without a better understanding of what you're going for, I can't give better advice than that.

Here's a rundown of some things initially wrong with your approach:

1. You don't want to specify `ng-controller` in a directive's template (your `menu` directive has `ng-controller="MenuController"`).  This is tightly coupling your directive to your controller (something you don't want to do) and it's causing Angular to instantiate it twice.  Directive's can have their own Controllers, and should be used in a situation like this.
2. You've got `<menu model="test">` which is telling Angular to look for a property called `test` in `$scope`, which doesn't exist.  I'm not entirely sure what you're going for here, so again, I can't really advise you on what's best without making assumptions.
3. Finally, they're not hurting anything, but you don't need those return statements in `MenuController` and `$scope.init`.  JavaScript functions can simply be "sub" routines without any return.

Comment: The idea is there are two separate directives. The goal is to pass a constant to menu, that will start the process. `<menu model="'brunch'">`(generate the first block of html above).

Comment: I re-read your question a bit after my original answer.  Check my edit.  You had some cross-cutting concerns with ngController and ngInit in your directive... those concerns would be better left to the directive so there's not such low cohesion.

Comment: I just updated my fiddle a bit to be more close to what i want.

Comment: How do I sync `which` and the service call to get the data?  Right now I am doing a e.g. `Menu.query({'category': 'brunch'})`.  I see you have hard coded everything.

Comment: You'd change the directive to use `controller` instead of `link` and inject the service as a dependency... http://jsfiddle.net/ALWQe/5/  This is why I suggested that it might be better to describe your approach, because automatically loading data from the (assuming) server when a directive is used seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to mold your latest fiddle into what I need.  If you clean up the post above to match closer to your fiddle I will accept.